# Is there a way to keep a script running in python while the screen is locked?

Tags: pyautogui, lockscreen

I'm trying to run a script in pyton in my company using the pyautogui lib

So I'd like to:

- Keep Running the script while the screen is locked, because we want to run the script and lock the screen and left the computer

Someone has any suggestion? I've tried to code `"pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'l')` but it hasn't worked.

Att.

--

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pyperclip
import PySimpleGUI as sg

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

Layout = [
[sg.Text("Por favor, insira o número de contas a serem canceladas")],
    [sg.InputText(key="contas")],
    [sg.Button("Iniciar"), sg.Button("Cancelar")],
]

Janela = sg.Window("Macro Encerramento Contas", Layout, margins=(100,50))

while True:
    evento, valores = Janela.read()
    if evento == sg.WIN_CLOSED or evento == "Cancelar":
        break
    if evento == "Iniciar":
        numero_contas = valores["contas"]
        x = int(numero_contas)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.2
        with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
            pyautogui.press('tab', presses=2)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c',interval=0.3)
        with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
            pyautogui.press(['tab', 'tab', 'tab'])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval=0.25)
        pyautogui.press('tab', presses=3)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        for i in range(x-1):
            pyautogui.leftClick(884, 5)
            pyautogui.press('down')
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
            with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
                pyautogui.press('tab')
            time.sleep(0.15)
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.press('tab')
            time.sleep(0.15)
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval=0.15)
            pyautogui.press('tab', presses=3)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(0.1)


#pyautogui.press('tab',presses=3)
#pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to lock the screen programmatically or how to keep a process running when the user locks the screen?

Comment: I'm asking how to keep a process running while the screen is locked.

Comment: AFAIK locking the screen shouldn't do anything to processes running, but then this is Windows. Did you read this? https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time/1023836#1023836  Seems to me this is one of the usual windows things where they introduce hidden features that break stuff. Apparently in some configurations windows will go to sleep when locked after a number of seconds.

Comment: Trying to keep a GUI automation script running when the computer is locked makes no sense - you can't interact with the GUI elements you're trying to interact with.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the PC doesn't get put to sleep, your script should continue to run - doesn't matter screen is locked or not.

If we are talking about *locking the screen* with Python, you can try do that:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

To *prevent you PC from sleep* you can use [wakepy](https://pypi.org/project/wakepy/):

```py
from wakepy import keep

with keep.running():
    ... # do stuff that takes long time
```

Comment: I don't know why but my script stop when the screen is locked,

" File "pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1722, in failSafeCheck
pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED. " 

I already tried to set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False

Comment: Do you tried to lock the screen programmatically, inside the script?

Comment: Yes but still not working, when the screen is locked my script simply stop running

Comment: Still Active, but is not running,

May I send you my script? I'm really begginer in python-

Comment: It seems that problem is not caused by your script. Maybe it's your system settings. Please go to your PC's 'Power Options' (Press 'Win' and type 'Edit power plan' and set 'Put the computer to sleep' to 'Never'). Hope this will help...

Comment: Unfortunately my settings are right, how can I send you my script?

Comment: If this is not a top secret:), you can just edit your question be adding of your code or providing a link to your Codepile or ReplIt

Comment: Ohh thx, I alredy eddited,

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that script that automates key pressing can be executed when PC is in locked state...

Comment: oh sure, I also believe that is not possible, but I'm really thankful for your help!!!